# I am using custom list adapter within a fragment but i am getting error, don't know how to handle it

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview

here is my fragment class code the error is with getApplicationContext(). Please some one tell me what to write instead of getApplicationContext.

**FragmentList.java**

```
package project.demo.com.reviewlisted;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Tappan on 7/31/2015.
 */
public class SimplipherReview extends Fragment {
    ListView l;
    private RevieweArrayAdapter C;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.simplipherreview, container, false);
        l = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listp);

        C= new RevieweArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.reviewdef);
        for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
        {
            RCard c = new RCard("Anwar Kamal","4.3", "Fast and quick");
            C.add(c);
        }
        l.setAdapter(C);
        l.setDivider(null);
        l.setDividerHeight(0);


        return view;

    }
}
```

i also have ReviewArrayAdapter class but i don't think so there is any need of including that code here because error is in fragmentList.java only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use getActivity() instead of getApplicationContext(). Anyway, send stacktrace of your error.